# Объясните по поводу && в JS

Tags: javascript

Можете объяснить почему:

```
const a = 3;
const b = -2;
console.log(b && a > 0);
```

Возвращает **true**, а код

```
const a = 3;
const b = -2;
console.log(a && b > 0);
```

Возвращает **false**?

Comment: А на самом деле вы хотели написать `a > 0 && b > 0`

Comment: а что по-вашему должно быть и почему?

Comment: потому что у логических операций приоритет меньше чем у операции сравнения

Comment: В первом случае `b && a > 0` выглядит так  `(b && a)` это 3 сравнение 3 > 0 . Во втором `a && b > 0` выглядит так  `(a && b)` это -2 сравнение -2 > 0

Comment: @Rudi откуда такая инфа?

Comment: А почитать в учебнике конечно https://learn.javascript.ru/logical-operators

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Если не ошибаюсь оператор `>` имеет приоритет выше чем `&&`.. И если даже вперед выполнялся бы `&&`, значения `a` и `b` "верны" соответственно вернут последнее верное значение.

Comment: @Rudi значит ты неправильно написал... потому что будет не `(b && a)`, а `(b && true)` и в другом моменте будет `(a && false)`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не правильно написал.

Answer (score 0):

Открываем документацию и находим там [приоритет операторов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table). Как видно, абсолютно у всех операторов сравнения приоритет выше чем у логический операторов.

Точно так же как и в математике, где в строчке без скобок приоритет у умножения и деления выше чем у сложения и вычитания. Т.е. мы сначала выполним `*` и `/` и только потом с получившимися результатами будем выполнять операции `+` и `-`.

Следовательно, когда мы пишем (буду без переменных писать значения):

```
3 && -2 > 0
```

то сначала выполняется сравнение и мы получаем:

```
3 && false
```

далее работает правило (*): Если левая часть может быть конвертирована в `false`, то будет возвращено левая часть иначе возвращается правая часть. `3` НЕ может быть конвертирован в `false`, следовательно возвращается правая часть и мы получаем `false`

Когда же мы пишем:

```
-2 && 3 > 0
```

то точно по такой же логике мы сначала получаем:

```
-2 && true
```

далее по правилу (*) мы получаем `true` т.к. отрицательные числа тоже НЕ могут быть конвертированы в `false`, значит возвращается правая часть

Более подробно можно прочитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#logical_operators)

### Небольшое отступление

По поводу правила (*). Я до замечания Grundy писал, что они оба преращаются в булевы значения и только потом мы получаем результат. Это просто универская дискретная математика у меня в голове осталась, где в конце должно быть либо 0 либо 1 :)

Но в JS это работает по другой логике и это очень важно (логический опреатор И):

- Во первых может ли быть конвертировано значение в `true` или `false` проверяется ТОЛЬКО для левой части выражения
- Из-за этого правила очень важно писать всё в нужном порядке иначе можно получить совершенно другой результат

Простой пример:

```
3 && 1 --> 1
```

но в обратном порядке:

```
1 && 3 --> 3
```

В обоих случаях левая часть может быть конвертирована в `true` потому мы получаем разный результат для разной последовательности

Точно такая же логика работает и со значениями `false`.

Например:

```
0 && '' --> 0
```

но в обратном порядке

```
'' && 0 --> ''
```

Конвертировать все значения в булевые и смотреть на конечный результат полезно, когда логическое оператор используется например в каком-либо условии

Например нам без разницы между таким выражением:

```
if (3 && 1)
```

и варажением:

```
if (1 && 3)
```

Блок `if` отработает в любом случае

Comment: _вот 3 превращается в true_ - значения ни во что не превращаются, 3 как была 3 так и остается 3.

Comment: @Grundy Как нет? Я [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#logical_operators) смотрел. И там напсиано, что если может быть конвертировано в `false` то возвращается одно значение, если нет то другое

Comment: @Grundy Я понял о чём ты, я не так выразился :) Щас поправлю

Comment: @Artem_K, исправил ответ и добавил чуть больше подробностей